# Wordwrapping in a surfaceView

Tags: android, textview, word-wrap, surfaceview

I have a surfaceView which I want to respond to any touch on it with its onTouch() method. However, I would also like to display a significant amount of text on the screen. There may be a significant amount of text; enough text that I would like for some word wrapping to occur. This doesn't seem possible using the Canvas drawText() method for the surfaceView. Is there a way to put a text view under my surfaceView, so that I can take advantage of the properties of a textView, but still have the full area of the surfaceView touchable? That is, I still want my surfaceView's onTouch() method to execute when I touch the text in the textView.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just write a method that will deal with the wordwrapping?

Comment: Meh, I guess I could. I was hoping there was something a little easier.